# String from file C++ BorlandC 3.1

Tags: c++, string, borland-c++

I'm trying to put the content of a file into a variable, but I'm having issues with BorlandC 3.1 .
I've read the documentation for this on http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ but, I don't have getline in Borland...

Can anyone point me to a way to get the string from the first line of the file into a variable ? Thanks.

Comment: I know this is not a helpful answer, but please consider not using Borland as a way to learn C++.  It's immensely outdated, and prevents you from using all the new features like STL.

Comment: Well, I'll love to do that, but tell the same to our teachers and examiners :(

Comment: @Bdesign: I assumed this was some kind of homework exercise!  In all seriousness, though, please consider asking your teacher why they insist on using something so antiquated; it does your learning a complete disservice!

Comment: It's not homework, it's just practice. I already know PHP pretty good I might say, learning C++ using Borland is a real pain.

Comment: @BDesign: then please ditch the outdated compiler! GCC is free enough, and very good in new c++ feature compliance.

Comment: If you really like Borland, then you can get [Borland C++ 5.5](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20633), which was the command-line compiler from C++ Builder 5. It has the benefits of being a 32-bit compiler, and reasonably standard-compliant. On the other hand, there's no shortage of free *recent* C++ compilers available, including GCC and Visual C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one `getline`. Use the `<iostream>` [one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) since BC++ 3.1 does not come with the one provided by `<string>` (because it precedes STL by quite a few years if I remember correctly).